# Make some portation of code not schedubale in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, device-driver

When every some of my `ioctl` is called then one `magic()` function is called in my driver and whenever that function is called in that code between start and end comment, should not be scheduled by any other process or thread.

```
magic()
{
// start

some code is here.

// end
}
```

What I want to do is: Whenever processor starts to execute code, after start, until it finishes up to end, it should not be scheduled by processor.

So how can I do that? Is this the same thing which is also called atomic process?

By keeping that code between mutex will serve that functionality?

Comment: use semaphores for this situation, if that code is not supposed to sleep use spin lock if its in interrupt context

Answer (score 1):

Once in a similar scenario when I needed a scrapbook kind of a place wherein multiple client threads would write and that be read by a thread acting as a server thread, what I had done was somewhat like this:
These functions I am referring to are just the examples here, try not to worry about arguments and sharing the variables within.

```
c1_thread_write() //let this be the unique function that client_thread_1 executes after it's inception  
{
   //some calls to open the scrapbook
   //the scrapbook thing I am referring to, is a buffer
   //Now I want to ensure that when client_thread_1 is writing, no other process or thread should be scheduled, which may somehow cause the client_thread_1 to exit this writing function without completing it.

   //so, I will create a MUTEX, lock it here as the first thing that gets executed in this function. MUTEX will be of ERROR_CHECK type
   //Start writing to the buffer, finish it
   //Unlock the mutex
   //call the pthread_join() and exit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This needs semaphore/spin lock depending upon the situation. Here is a simple character driver code. When device open function is called, it sees if any other process has opened the device, if so, it waits for it to close. If the device has not being used by any other process, it can open the device. This is achieved by using semaphores. Process must access the code by taking the semaphore, once completed, it must/should release the semaphore. 
Below are the open and close functions.

```
static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
    if(down_interruptible(&sem) != 0) {//take the semaphore
        printk(KERN_ALERT "megharajchard : the device has been opened by some other device, unable to open lock\n");
        return -1;
    }
    //buff_rptr = buff_wptr = device_buffer;
    printk(KERN_INFO "megharajchard : device opened succesfully\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here the process tries to open device, it must take the semaphore, once taken, no other process will be allowed to open the device.

Below is the close device function where the process will release the semaphore so that other process can open the device and use it.

```
static int device_close(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
    up(&sem);// release the semaphore
    printk(KERN_INFO "megharajchard : device has been closed\n");
    return ret;
}
```

Atomic means the situation where a process cannot sleep, usually encountered while running in interrupt context. Where while executing the process is not allowed to sleep. To achieve locking in such situation we must use spinlock.

Let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: @Meghraj: I have suggested some edits in your answer if you don't mind.